# How do I get all the icons in iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I came across the project which gets all the icons bundled with iOS. However, I don't remember where I found that project.

All I want to do is grab all the images/icons (Battery status icon, network icons, gps icons, etc) from iOS.

Any hints where can I find help for this problem? Where should I start from?

Comment: https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) extracts all the artwork and emoji symbols contained in UIKit into png files.

Comment: I had referred the same project sometime ago. I was unable to find that. Many Thanks for the link.